# What does "col_level" do in the melt function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**From the documentation:**

```
pd.melt(frame, id_vars=None, value_vars=None, var_name=None, value_name='value', col_level=None)
```

What does `col_level` do?

Examples with different values of `col_level` would be great.

**My current dataframe is created by the following:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'},
                   'B': {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 5},
                   'C': {0: 2, 1: 4, 2: 6}})
df.columns = [list('ABC'), list('DEF'), list('GHI')]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

> **col_level** : int or string, optional
>
> If columns are a MultiIndex then use this level to melt.

And examples:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'},
                   'B': {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 5},
                   'C': {0: 2, 1: 4, 2: 6}})
#use Multiindex.from_arrays for set levels names
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([list('ABC'), list('DEF'), list('GHI')],
                                        names=list('abc'))
print (df)
a  A  B  C
b  D  E  F
c  G  H  I
0  a  1  2
1  b  3  4
2  c  5  6
```

---

```
#melt by first level of MultiIndex
print (df.melt(col_level=0))
   a value
0  A     a
1  A     b
2  A     c
3  B     1
4  B     3
5  B     5
6  C     2
7  C     4
8  C     6

#melt by level a of MultiIndex
print (df.melt(col_level='a'))
   a value
0  A     a
1  A     b
2  A     c
3  B     1
4  B     3
5  B     5
6  C     2
7  C     4
8  C     6
```

---

```
#melt by level c of MultiIndex
print (df.melt(col_level='c'))
   c value
0  G     a
1  G     b
2  G     c
3  H     1
4  H     3
5  H     5
6  I     2
7  I     4
8  I     6
```

Comment: Tried using this, and it works:
pd.melt(df, col_level='b', id_vars = ['D'])

But why doesn't this work: 
pd.melt(df, col_level='b', id_vars = ['D'], value_vars=['E'])

Thanks!

Comment: I test it and not so easy answer. But not possible use `value_vars` with `col_level` together. Btw, practically parameter `col_level` is used very rare, so is possible there are some bugs.